# Comparsion with the actual image and screenshot taken from the mobile device

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, automation

Problem:

We have a web page which we load inside the Android App and iOS App. the web page is having a header slot and footer slot and a banner slot for the image.

When developers attach the URL's of the images to the header, footer and banner slots most of the times the images are not fitting within the screens. 
1. They cross the boundaries of the screen size
2. Image with text content is hidden by the button in the banner slot

We have to do an automation which actually checks if the images are not overlapped with the button in the banner slot and the images are not going beyond the screen sizes after the images appear in the device.

I checked few ideas like Sikuli and some screenshot comparison libraries. What I'm looking for is some tool that is closer to the human recognition which can tell whether the image is going beyond the limit.

Can someone tell me which library or tool I can use to automate this?

I'm uploading the image how our web page looks like[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look into [**Espresso**](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/). It's a UAT framework for Android. It basically allows you to auto test your app at runtime.

You could assert something like the following:

```
onView(withId(R.id.headerImage))
    .check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
onView(withId(R.id.bodyImage))
    .check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
onView(withId(R.id.footerImage))
    .check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
```

If any of these items are cut off, your test will throw an error.

Comment: image slots are inside a web page and I don't have the id's for the image as it is the webview